# Multiple Message Queue for multiple data

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, message-queue

I am trying to make a synchronous service asynchronous using message queue. A brief summary of the service:

The service basically gives rewards to user when a condition is met. The rewards are of x types and each reward type have y number of rewards. We use mutex locks to make sure data is consistent when there are multiple request for a reward.

Now I am trying to scale the service using message queues. Suppose there are n number of games running parallely, I am thinking to create n*x*y number of queues. Each queue will be unique to different reward type for each games.

Eg. If 1000 games are running parallely and there are 10 reward types, there will be 1000*10 different queues.

I am new to message queues. Is it feasible to have such system considering the cost? What are the drawbacks of such system? I heard about MQTT and rabbitMQ and thinking of using either one.

Comment: MQTT is not a message queuing system

Comment: @hardillb thank you for mentioning it. Can it only be used with IoT devices?

Comment: No, it's a perfectly good pub/sub system, it's just not a message queue

Comment: Look at temporal.io. It would allow modeling each user as a separate durable object.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the scenario. Why are you trying to create a queue ? What are you planning to do from this queue ?

Comment: @SantoshBalaji I have added the scenario in the question.